# Trying to load more than 32 hfiles to one family of one region

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am importing a lot of files into HBase table, so I decided to use Bulk Load [9.8. Bulk Loading](http://hbase.apache.org/book/arch.bulk.load.html). I have managed to prepare data via MapReduce job, but when I try to complete load using this command

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles <src> <target_table>
```

I got following error:

```
ERROR mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles: Trying to load more than 32 hfiles to family d of region with start key
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Trying to load more than 32 hfiles to one family of one region
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.doBulkLoad(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:288)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.run(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:842)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.main(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:847)
```

Do you know how to change number of hfiles per family and regions. And it is possible to change it from CLI?

Answer (score 4):

You can either configure **"hbase.hregion.max.filesize"** in hbase-site.xml file or as -D argument to higher value (may be according to your input file size) so that number of hfiles created will be less. *Default value is 10 GB*.

OR you can configure **"hbase.mapreduce.bulkload.max.hfiles.perRegion.perFamily"** in hbase-site.xml or as -D argument to a higher value (to the maximum number of hfiles created for a column family this can be found from HDFS). *Default value is 32*.

Answer (score 2):

@ashish's answer is correct. To use it in shell try with:

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles -Dhbase.mapreduce.bulkload.max.hfiles.perRegion.perFamily=1024 <SOURCE> <TABLE>
```

Comment: I was facing the same issue, adding the suggestion fixed my issue but I am still having an issue. All the Hfiles aren't loaded. Some portion of the Hfiles is not loaded. i.e 
initially the size was 3.9 G   /output/day=01/g1Out/d
after the loading the size is
26.0 M /output/day=01/g1Out/d

Any suggestions on How can i load the Hfiles completely?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this?
https://hbase.apache.org/xref/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/LoadIncrementalHFiles.html

```
 public static final String MAX_FILES_PER_REGION_PER_FAMILY = "hbase.mapreduce.bulkload.max.hfiles.perRegion.perFamily";

 maxFilesPerRegionPerFamily = conf.getInt(MAX_FILES_PER_REGION_PER_FAMILY, 32);
```

You can try to change this property using Configuration object you are passing to the job.

Comment: Thank you, I was checking this. I tried to change the hbase.mapreduce.bulkload.max.hfiles.perRegion.perFamily property in my hbase-site.xml. But it didnt work for me :(

Comment: I suppose that you have to set it on job level, not on hbase level. Different Hadoop distributions treat configurations in different way. Just set it property to configuration object before  calling LoadIncrementalHFiles

Comment: I do not really know how to do that. Can you show me some example? Thank you a lot!

Comment: I see, you do it thorugh cli, I do it using java. Did you try to this: hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles <src> <target_table> -Dhbase.mapreduce.bulkload.max.hfiles.perRegion.perFamily=128 or hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles <src> <target_table> -D hbase.mapreduce.bulkload.max.hfiles.perRegion.perFamily=128 See this: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html#Specifying+Configuration+Variables+with+the+-D+Option

Comment: Anyway, your LoadIncrementalHFiles should get zookeer quorum and zookeeper client port in order to interact with hbase. Did you try to set hbase.mapreduce.bulkload.max.hfiles.perRegion.perFamily here: "/etc/hadoop/conf/hbase-site.xml" on the host where you run LoadIncrementalHFiles? Your comment is not crear, you mentioned that you tried to set something somewhere.

Comment: It would be good to know what are the implications of increasing this value. If they have bothered to create this limit there must be a reason. I have already checked the source code and it does not have any comments on this regard.

Comment: This link has more information: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/47586/i-am-getting-javaioioexception-trying-to-load-more.html